# play 2.0 template the right way to reuse footer template

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have a footer template which has a input and submit for email subscription. The footer is used by every page. When subscription succeeds, it will redirect back to current page. However, I found out I am passing a string value to indicate what current page is. What is the best way to have a footer template for Play 2.0 application?

**footer.scala.html**

```
@(page: String)
<div id="footer">
    <div class="input-append">
        <form action="@routes.ApplicationController.saveSubscription(page)"
                                method="post">
        <input type="text" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Your Email" />
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
        </form>
    </div> <!-- /input-append -->  
</div> <!-- /footer -->
```

**ApplicationController.java**

```
public class ApplicationController extends Controller {
    public static Result saveSubscription(String page) {
        ..........
        flash("success", "success message");
        if (page.equals("page1")) {
            return redirect(routes.ApplicationController.page1());
        } else if (page.equals("page2")) {
            return redirect(routes.ApplicationController.page2());
        } 
    }
}
```

**page1.scala.html**

```
@main("Page 1") {
    <div>
    <p>page 1</p>
    </div>
    @footer("page1")
}
```

**page2.scala.html**

```
@main("Page 2") {
    <div>
    <p>page 2</p>
    </div>
    @footer("page2")
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I follow @virtualeyes but it seems the subscribe.js is never been called. Here is the New setup.

**main.scala.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/vendor/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/subscribe.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
       @footer()
    </body>
</html>
```

**footer.scala.html**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="input-append">                  
      <form id="_form" action="@routes.ApplicationController.simpleSubscription()">
        <input type="text" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Your Email" />
        <input id="_process" class="btn" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
      </form>
    </div> <!-- /input-append -->  
</div> <!-- /footer -->
```

**routes**

```
POST    /subscribe  controllers.ApplicationController.simpleSubscription()
```

**Now I got his error:**
Action not found
For request 'GET /subscribe?emailAddress=fdsaf%40rte.com'

I am not sure if it is because method="post" is removed. If I put it back, then the result will return but will redirect to /subscribe page. I also set a breakpoint at subscribe.js but it doesn't seem to be called at all.

**EDIT 2 - Working**

after I changed a little bit for subscribe.coffee and get rid of main.coffee, now it's working.

**subscribe.coffee**

```
$('#_process').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()

  isValid = $('#_form').validate().form()
  if isValid
    $('#_process').spin()
    $.ajax
      type: "POST"
      url:  $('#_form').attr('action')
      data: $('#_form').serialize()
      success: (data) ->
        $('#_status > div').removeClass('alert-error').addClass('alert-success')
        $('#_status > div').html( data )
        $('#_status').fadeIn()
        fade = () -> $('#_status').fadeOut('slow')
        setTimeout fade, 2000
        $('#_process').spin('stop')

      error: (data) ->
        $('#_status > div').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-error')
        $('#_status > div').html( data.responseText )
        $('#_status').fadeIn()
        fade = () -> $('#_status').fadeOut('slow')
        setTimeout fade, 2000
        $('#_process').spin('stop')

      complete: () -> $('#_process').spin('stop')
```

**footer.scala.html**

```
 <div id="_status">
    <div class="alert alert-error"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="input-append">
    <form id="_form" action="@routes.ApplicationController.simpleSubscription">
       <input type="text" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Your Email" />
       <input id="_process" class="btn" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
    </form>
    <div id="_spin"></div>
  </div> <!-- /input-append -->
```

> The spin() function is from  https://github.com/pshizzle/spin.coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is the way™

```
//footer.scala.html
<div id="footer">
  <div class="input-append">
    <form id="_form" action="@routes.ApplicationController.saveSubscription">
      <input type="text" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Your Email" />
      <input id="_process" class="btn" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
      <img id="spinner" src="/assets/img/loader.gif" alt="loading..." />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="status">
  <div class="alert alert-error"></div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
  #spinner, #status { display: none; }
</style>

//ApplicationController.java
public class ApplicationController extends Controller {
  public static Result saveSubscription() {
    // save subscription
    ...
    // pseudo code
    if(success) 
      Ok( i18n("subscription success").toJson() );
    else
      Conflict( i18n("subscription fail").toJson() );
  }
}

//main.coffee
jQuery ->
  $.ajaxSetup
    type:     "POST"
    cache:    false
    dataType: "json"

  # prevent form submit on keypress
  $('form').find('input').keypress (e) -> e.preventDefault() if(e.which == 13)

  jParse = (data) -> 
    try jQuery.parseJSON(data)
    catch e
      data

  jText = (data) -> jParse(data.responseText)

  toSuccess = (msg) -> 
    $('#status > div').removeClass('alert-error').addClass('alert-success')
    $('#status > div').html( jParse(msg) )
    $('#status').fadeIn()

  toFail = (data) -> 
    $('#status > div').html( jText(data) )
    $('#status').fadeIn()

//subscribe.coffee
jQuery ->
  $('#_process').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    isValid = $('#_form').validate().form() // assumes jQuery validation plugin
    if isValid
      $('#spinner').show()
      $.ajax
        data: $('#_form').serialize()
        success: (msg) ->
          toSuccess(msg)
          fade = () -> $('#status').fadeOut('slow')
          setTimeout fade, 2000

        error: (data) -> toFail(data)

        complete: () -> $('#spinner').hide()
```

Comment: I created subscribe.coffee and main.coffee, then I put these two scripts main.min.js and subscribe.min.js at my footer.scala.html. However, I got one error. Uncaught ReferenceError: toFail is not defined. What is the issue?

Comment: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: toFail is not defined' is an alert message for subscribe.min.js on google chrome.

Comment: This 'Uncaught ReferenceError: toFail is not defined' only happens when I put the <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/main.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> and <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/subscribe.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> at the end of footer.

Comment: arghhh, sorry about that, you need "jQuery ->" at the top of subscribe.coffee file -- I edited accordingly (remember coffee is indentation/white space based, so "jQuery ->" must be at top of indentation hierarchy)

Comment: I remember I did try this. Thanks. Do you have time to check my edit? Does my edit look good?

Comment: hmmmm, not sure if Java is same as Scala when it comes to .coffee compilation; in my Play 2 Scala setup I omit the file extension and the framework does the magic (i.e. compiles .coffee to .js and sets <script src=...> tag accordingly).  Looks like you've made progress, my intention was more, here's how you can do it in AJAX without redirecting the user anywhere, the user just stays put (which is great if an error occurs, the form is still filled out, and a json error response allows the user to recover/figure out wht's wrong)

Comment: I think I'm using Ajax even after I modified your script. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing ready to use redirect address in hidden field?

`footer`

```
@(returnPath: String)
<form action="@routes.ApplicationController.saveSubscription()" method="post">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="returnPath" value="@returnPath" />
</form>
```

`page1`

```
@main("Page 1") {
    ...
    <!-- it's important to use toString at the end -->
    @footer(routes.ApplicationController.page1.toString)
}
```

or even better: giving the `path` from the current `request()`

```
@main("Page 1") {
    ...
    @footer(request.path)
}
```

`controller`

```
public static Result saveSubscription() {
    ...
    flash("success", "success message");
    return redirect(form().bindFromRequest().get("returnPath"));
}
```

BTW: maybe it would be just easier and nicer to use AJAX form? in such case you are avoiding redundant reloads at all (and finding objects and rendering whole templates again and again, etc etc.)